# SharePoint OnPrem DNS URL to Online

Tags: url, online, dns

Am I able to assign DNS web URL's to my SharePoint Online site collections? Or am I limited to the tenant address?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in SharePoint Online.

The only things you can choose:

- TenantName. This will always look like https://TenantName**.sharepoint.com**/ You can choose tenant name **only once you create it**.
- Site collection path. Either /teams/ or /sites/
- Site collection URL. /sites/New_Site_colleciton_url

So any new site collection you create will look either like

> https://TenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/NewSiteCollection

or

> https://TenantName.sharepoint.com/teams/NewSiteCollection

And there is nothing you can do about it. Not in 2017 anyway.

**Update:**

I've heard suggestions of getting your custom domain. Even if you get your custom domain - it will only affect your user's email addresses. The tenant URL will remain the same. Yes, you can host a site on https://yourdomain and have a redirect to https://TenantName.sharepoint.com, but it will not change the URL of your site collection. And users won't be able to use https://yourdomain URL in any applications like Word, onedrive, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are limited to the provided tenant address. 
However, you can try buying a domain of your own,and map it to your site collection.